# How to monitor the subprocesses using C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, process, monitor

The requirement is to start a process -- here we name it processA. In processA, there will be some commands started. When each of the subprocesses is started, I want to get the subprocess information such as the start command string which is used to start the subprocess. I have no idea on it. BTW, my programing language is C/C++.

Comment: Isn't the command string you gave to start the subprocess? So you alrady have it! What other information you want to know? also this is highly system dependent, so please state your os and platform.

Comment: C/C++ isn't a language

Comment: Thank you @fluter For example, by starting a command named "cmdA", cmdA will start another command -- make -f Makefile. What I want to get are the compiling commands and linking commands and their arguments. My target OS includes windows and linux.

Comment: Those information are in the Makefile, right? You can get them from the Makefile.

Comment: Yes, these information are indeed in Makefile. But the format of Makefile is too complex, I have to process many variables, targets, child-makefiles, etc, and have to parse the file. I think it much easier to catch them from running the make commands.

Comment: Is it an option to change the makefile to replace all standard commands that special ones that first send a *message* and then start the real command? Makefiles often use the `MACRO=real_command` idiom at their top...

Comment: The "make -f Makefile" is one of these processes need to be monitored, there are many other different processes. I think the only way to collect them all in one method will be reading the command line string.